# Chrome Extension - If a specific webpage is opened then

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension to do this:
If in browser is opened a specific webpage (check a list of webpages ex. google.com; yahoo.com, etc.) open in new tab a specific page.

For example:
When I open booking.com I want the plugin to open a new tab with airbnb.com. This action will save a cookie with life time for x days to prevent plugin to open airbnb.com in this nuber of days.

booking.com opens airbnb.com;
website2 opens website3
website4 opens website5
etc.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {
    if (tab.url.indexOf("https://www.yahoo.co.jp/") != -1) {
      chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://nory-soft.web.app/" });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: How to stop extension to open new tabs after the first one was open. If I navigate and change pages on https://www.yahoo.co.jp/ new tabs will be open.

Comment: Check if the target URL is already open with `chrome.tabs.query()`.

Comment: Hi. I search but I cant find how to do it. Can you give me an example? Thank you.